# Bypass preloader and load meshes from GWT server side

Tags: html, libgdx, gwt-rpc

I currently have 6 animated models each between 5Mb and 8Mb each. When using each one individually it can take a little time to download them. I need to load these models up as and when I need them and not in the preloader of libGdx. All 6 models will take a long time to download in the preloader so I'm trying to bypass it.

I've used both GWT and libGdx many times but not together. This project is purely a html one and I'm familiar with classes that need to be serialised so data can be transferred back and forth using GWT's RPC methods.

So far I've come up with 2 ideas of doing this:

1. Transfer the model data and rebuild the mesh from scratch. This
   would take a lot of time and just wouldn't work. Plus it's likely I'll lose such data like animations.
2. Using LibGdx's
   ModelData class which would work perfect, but unfortunately non of
   the main class and sub classes are serialised.

The current project has interfaces that bridge the platform specific from the 'core' to the 'html' which can then async the RPC calls. These work with libGdx just great.

Is there a way of skipping the preloader and loading the models on demand when they are needed?

If you need anymore information I'll be glad to add that in.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Dynamic Asset Loading with libGDX and GWT example by MonsterOfCookie: https://github.com/MonsterOfCookie/libGDXGwtHtmlExample

Disadvantage is that you have to compile your own libGDX fork because Monster's PR was not merged. (But for working seriously with libGDX' GWT backend you'll probably need your own fork anyway)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I was considering looking into a fork so that I could serialise all the classes I need, but I don't know how long it would take or whether it would work.

Comment: In the end I moved away from libGdx in favour of blend4web which has dynamic loading and is easy to incorporate into a websocket project. I realised that serialising the classes wouldn't work on it's own because I then had material data to transfer. I didn't get to try out the link you sent because blend4web works for what I need it for.